# Login automatically in webpage with PHP using Windows Credentials

Tags: php, windows, ldap

I have an intranet application, done in html and PHP. The login is made with Active Directory credentials using LDAP. Is there a way in which i can skip the login if a user is registered in windows with a domain valid user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use some plugin which will do the authorization.
2. I found a link about that auto login function, maybe the principle of the method will apply to you: 
   https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22865/auto-login-using-active-directory-and-windows-authentication
3. Develop an ActiveX component?